# Paralellizing Recursive Functions

Tags: c, multithreading, recursion, openmp

i have the following recursive function:

```
    
     void find_words(char grid[ROWS][COLS], int row, int col, char prefix[MAX_WORD_LENGTH], int visited[ROWS][COLS], node_t** table) {
    // Mark current cell as visited
    visited[row][col] = 1;

    // Append current letter to prefix
    char current_word[MAX_WORD_LENGTH];
    strncpy(current_word, prefix, MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
    strncat(current_word, &grid[row][col], 1);

    // Check if prefix is a word in the dictionary
    if (ht_search(table, current_word)) 
    {
      
         int is_Exist=0;
         int i;
      
        for (i=0;i<found_words_counter;i++)
         {

            if(strcmp(found_words[i],current_word)==0)
            {
               is_Exist=1;
               break;
            }
         }  
         if(!is_Exist)  
            {   
             
                    
              strncpy(found_words[found_words_counter++],current_word,MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
                         
            }
       }
   

    // Check for words that can be formed by extending the prefix
    int i, j;
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) shared(grid, visited, table, current_word)
      for (i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
        for (j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
            if (row+i >= 0 && row+i < ROWS && col+j >= 0 && col+j < COLS && !visited[row+i][col+j] && !(i == 0 && j == 0)) {
                find_words(grid, row+i, col+j, current_word, visited, table);
            }
        }
    }

    // Mark current cell as unvisited
    visited[row][col] = 0;

}
```

this function takes in a matrix of size ROWS*COLS of letters that the user inputs in the main function, then recursively backtracks and adds every other letter in the matrix to a prefix, this prefix is checked if it exists in a hash table that has about 50k words, the hash table is impelemented as an array of pointers to a linked list, if a prefix is found in the hash table, the prefix gets added to an array of strings, after this find_words function is finished, this array of strings will just be printed.

now what i tried to do was to paralellize the program with openmp to make it run faster, but after the user inputs the letters of the matrix, the program spends alot of time running,almost like its in an infinite loop, so im not sure where the issue is, running the program in serial gives the correct output after about 40 seconds,so im not sure what am i doing wrong exactly.

the code segment that runs the find_words function in the main function is structured like this:

```
 #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j) shared(grid, visited, table, prefix)
     for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
       find_words(grid, i, j, prefix, visited, table);
    }
   }
```

is it possible for recursive functions to be parallelized even? and if so, how can i paralellize the find_words function?

Comment: OT: beware of `strncpy`, it doesn't do what you think it does. You might end up without a null terminator.

Comment: It's possible (there are different solutions, including yours), but you have to be very careful about race conditions, i.e. different threads that read/write the same variables, particularly the `visited` array here. I think here that different threads may  simultaneously test the same element of `visited`, both making a recursive call on that element, which is not what you want...

Comment: It actually looks like that even without OpenMP at all, your code can go to an infinite loop. What is unclear to me: do you want each (row,col) be visited only once, or can it be visited several times?

Comment: @PierU  each (row,col) is to be visited only once, also as i mentioned in the question, i ran the program without  OpenMP and it ran fine and gave the correct output.

Comment: From what I can see, even in the serial version a given (row,col) can be visited multiple times. Maybe it has no consequence (apart from consuming CPU for nothing), but it can be different with multiple threads. Why do you set `visited[row][col] = 0;` at the end of the routine? If you don't want to visit it twice, shouldn't it stay at 1?

Comment: its because i do want a (row,col) to be visited by other recursive calls, but only after the current (row,col) finished exploring its all neighbors first, if that makes sense.

Comment: This is contradictory: "each (row,col) is to be visited only once" and "i do want a (row,col) to be visited by other recursive calls"...

Comment: "but only after the current (row,col) finished exploring its all neighbors first, if that makes sense." --> it doesn't really make sense to me, because you have no control on the moment each thread will visit a given (row,col)